# React-Native - fastlane screenshots with TabNavigation

Tags: react-native, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

I'm using fastlane in my react native for taking screenshots for the release phase, however I' quite in trouble concerning the navigation with TabNavigation from `react-navigation`.

How can I ask for a tap() on my tabNavigation's icons on the `[...]Test.swift` file in the `testExample()` method ? 
Using testID, but how to id for the component of tabNavigation ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am running into this right now.

Comment: Yeap what I did, is that I added small transparent buttons with `OnPress () => doNavigation()` on my views for manage the transitions between the scenes.